# com.android.camera.action.CROP doesn't work at landscape mode

Tags: android, android-intent, camera, crop, onactivityresult

I have an issue: need to take photo with camera and then show screen with possibility to crop photo that is taken. I added suchfunction:

```
protected void callCropPhoto(Uri uri) {
        try {
            Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
            intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/*");
            intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
            intent.putExtra("aspectX", avatar.getWidth());
            intent.putExtra("aspectY", avatar.getHeight());
            intent.putExtra("outputX", avatar.getWidth());
            intent.putExtra("outputY", avatar.getHeight());
            intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
            startActivityForResult(intent, CROP_PHOTO_REQUEST_CODE);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // Some devices can't support image cropping.
        }
    }
```

When I get result from camera with photo I call this function with temporary uri to taken photo. When calls onActivityResult usualy I get RESULT_OK and data - all works good. But on one device (android version 2.3.4) in landscape mode I got RESULT_CANCELED and no screen with cropping appear. What is the problem?

Comment: Android does not have a `CROP` `Intent`: http://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html

Comment: but in portrait orientation all is fine. Android have different intents for portait and landscape orientation or this intent maybe can't support landscape orientation?

Comment: No, I am saying that there is no guarantee that any device honors that `Intent` action, and there is no guarantee what will happen for devices that do have some app that honors that `Intent` action. I am saying that talented programmers do not rely upon such `Intent` actions, but instead use something that is more reliable, like a library. The previous comment contains a hyperlink to a Web page with more details.

Comment: How I see it, this Android supports Intent and Crop, because in portrait orientation all works fine. Using external libraries can cause more problems, because first of all - it's more size of apk file; it can provide more errors and exception; also it is irrationally to include one more library to the project only for supporting feature, that, probably, user will not use or one device will not support.

Comment: "this Android supports Intent and Crop, because in portrait orientation all works fine" -- you have one device. There are over 750 million Android devices, representing thousands of models. "Using external libraries can cause more problems" -- then you should not be doing software development. Pretty much anything written in the past 30 years, outside of pure assembler, involves libraries in one form or another.